# How can I make a table appear in custom format using CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-tables

[image]

I am trying to make a table which is automatically generated by RAILS in the default format to  look in the way I want it using CSS.

I.e. If you have looked into the image, I want the third column to appear as a row . Is this Possible through CSS ?

Comment: Currently, there's no `colspan` (or `rowspan`) CSS equivalent.

Comment: Not without JavaScript. And, I must add, that I think a `table` is the wrong tool for, essentially, a list of personal details...

Comment: David, Should i Edit the post for a solution using java script  or CSS ? can you suggest me any keywords to look for such a requirement ? 
Thanks

Comment: @DavidThomas It looks like tabular data to me...

Comment: As it currently is (three columns) then yes; it's tabular. In the preferred version, it looks more like a list of personal details...

Comment: The Server automatically creates a Table in the page . I want something which can make it look like that tweaking CSS or javascript file

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript, restyling your table is pretty easy. Let's assume that your table is called `your-table`. Select your table, and move the last cell to a newly created row, and insert the row after the current row.

Because you're adding rows to the table, make sure that you start at the end of the table. If you use `for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)`, your page will get in an infinite loop.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QP8ga/**

```
function refactorTable(table){
    var rows = table.rows;
    for(var i=rows.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = rows[i].cells[2];
        td.colSpan = "2";
        tr.appendChild(td);
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(tr, rows[i].nextSibling)
    }
}
window.onload = function(){
    var table_IDs = ["your-table", "another-table"];
    for(var i=0; i<table_IDs.length; i++) refactorTable(table_IDs[i]);
}
```

The previous code is modified to support multiple tables. The fiddle shows the basic example with one table.

Answer (score 1):

As an academic exercise, here's a pure CSS solution. Sadly, it will only work in browsers that properly support modern CSS. No IE support.

```
th { 
    display:none; 
}

table, tbody, tr, td { 
    display:block; 
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    border : 0px solid black;
}

table { 
    border-width : 1px 1px 0px; 
}

td:nth-child(1) { 
    width :50%; 
    float:left; 
}

td:nth-child(2) { 
    width :50%; 
    float:left; 
    border-left-width: 1px;
}

td:nth-child(3) { 
    clear:both; 
    border-width: 1px 0px; 
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/FjBdL/5/

Comment: Nice solution. The only downside of this method is that the table elements don't support `vertical-align` any more, because you've added `display:block` to the table elements.

Comment: Looks good but , When i increase the number of columns for another table, it looks messed up , I tried adding 2 more td and nth-child(4),nth-child(5).but doesn't work.  Any quick fix to do this ?

Comment: @Vivek - The principle should be extendible to further columns. How do you want columns 4 and 5 to appear on your layout?

Comment: @Alohci Solved it. Thanks for the help everyone :)